# illegal instruction gnu assembly

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, x86-64

```
.globl start
.section .text
_start:
    movq $2, %rbx
    movq $3, %rcx
    movq $1, %rax

mainloop:
      addq $0, %rcx
      jz complete
      mulq %rbx
      decq %rcx


      jmp mainloop
complete:
       movq %rax, %rdi
       movq $60, %rax
     syscall
```

I have been trying to run this code, but keep getting an

> illegal instruction

through the assembler.
I cannot figure why it is supposed to run through GNU assembler.

Comment: Do you get a line number, or is the illegal instruction due to the assembler itself crashing? What version do you use? The code works fine here.

Comment: im using cygwin64 or Msys2 mingw64 im not sure how to debug with gdb i used (gdb) layout asm but got Cannot enable the TUI when output is not a terminal also use exponent.s -o exponent.o then exponent.o -o exponent then ./ to execute than get this illegal isnstruction

Comment: how to join your group Jester with ##asm

Comment: I don't think syscalls work in cygwin or msys. You need WSL. You can use IRC client or [the web interface](https://web.libera.chat/##asm)

Comment: You can rewrite the code to use `main` instead of `_start` and `jmp exit` (might be `_exit`) at the end instead of the `syscall`. Make sure you link with the C library.

Comment: `syscall` itself isn't an illegal instruction in a native Windows process, so you *can* use it in Cygwin or MSys, but you don't get the Linux ABI, you get the native Windows NT set of system calls!  So execution probably falls off the end your code after `syscall` returns an error.  Unless it crashes without reaching `_start:` in the first place, since `_start` maybe isn't special when linking a Windows `.exe`.  Anyway, in practice you should do what Jester said and write a `main`, if you don't want to use Linux to run this Linux code.